# What conditions on a function's derivative will satisfy given conditions?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R^2 \to\mathbb R$ be of class $C^1$ with $f(2,-1)=-1$. Set $$G(x,y,u) = f(x,y)+u^2 \\ H(x,y,u)=ux+3y^3+u^3$$
The equations $G(x,y,u)=0$ and $H(x,y,u)=0$ have solutions $(x,y,z)= (2,-1,1)$

a) What conditions on $Df$ ensure that there are $C^1$ functions $x=g(y)$ and $u=h(y)$ defined on an open set in $\mathbb R$ that satisfy both equations, such that $g(-1)=2$ and $h(-1)=1$?

b) Under the conditions of (a), assuming that $Df(2,-1)=[1 -3]$, find $g^\prime(-1)$ and $h^\prime(-1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to apply the i[mplicit function theorem.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem). Which gives in your case that the determinant of the matrix

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(2,1) & 2\\
1 & 5
\end{pmatrix}$$ should not vanish. Hence following condition

$$5 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(2,1) -2 \neq 0$$ for question a).

You can find $g$ and $h$ derivatives also using the implicit function theorem.

Comment: Why should the determinant of the matrix $A$ not be $0$? How did you calculate this matrix? Be clearer, please.

Comment: @user425181 You needs to know the implicit function theorem. And I provided a link to this theorem in my answer.