# Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ be of class $C^1$, with $f(2,-1)=-1$. Set $G(x,y,u)=f(x,y)+u^2, H(x,y,u)= ux+3y^3+u^3$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

**Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ be of class $C^1$, with $f(2,-1)=-1$. Set $G(x,y,u)=f(x,y)+u^2, H(x,y,u)= ux+3y^3+u^3$.**

**(a) What conditions on $Df$ ensure that there are $C^1$ functions $x = g(y)$ and $u = h(y)$ defined on an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ that satisfy both equations, such that $g(−1) = 2$ and $h(−1) = 1$?**

**(b)  Under the conditions of (a), and assuming that $Df(2, -1) = [1  -3]$,
find $g'(-1)$ and $h'(-1)$.**

There is already a post about this here [What conditions on a function's derivative will satisfy given conditions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1677499/what-conditions-on-a-functions-derivative-will-satisfy-given-conditions) but it does not seem very clear to me.

The truth is that I am very confused about this problem, could someone explain to me in detail what should I do?

For example for (a) I have thought that you can apply the implicit function theorem to $f$ to find $g$, the problem is that $f(2,-1)=-1\neq 0$ and I need $f(2,-1)=0$, how could I do this? How do I do with the other questions? Thank you very much.

Comment: You can see my question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2817911/munkres-section9-question-3-solving-gx-y-u-fx-y-u2-and-hx-y-u too.